# Google API Quota Usage Count

Tags: javascript, google-api, quotas

Is there any way to get Google API Quota limits and usage count for give API Key?

I know I can view API Quota limits from https://console.developers.google.com,
but I would like to query the usage programmatically.

How do I proceed? Is there any solution?

Thank you.